# Plot wont display in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using the following bit of code to plot two arrays of the same length -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import linregress

G_mag_values = [11.436, 11.341, 11.822, 11.646, 11.924, 12.057, 11.884, 11.805, 12.347, 12.662, 12.362, 12.555, 12.794, 12.819, 12.945, 12.733, 12.789, 12.878, 12.963, 13.094, 13.031, 12.962, 13.018, 12.906, 13.016, 13.088, 13.04, 13.035, 13.094, 13.032, 13.216, 13.062, 13.083, 13.126, 13.101, 13.089, 13.073, 13.182, 13.116, 13.145, 13.235, 13.161, 13.154, 13.383, 13.315, 13.429, 13.461, 13.287, 13.494, 13.459, 13.478, 13.534, 13.536, 13.536, 13.483, 13.544, 13.564, 13.544, 13.608, 13.655, 13.665, 13.668, 13.697, 13.649, 13.742, 13.756, 13.671, 13.701, 13.788, 13.723, 13.697, 13.713, 13.708, 13.765, 13.847, 13.992, 13.706, 13.79, 13.783, 13.844, 13.945, 13.928, 13.936, 13.956, 13.898, 14.059, 13.945, 14.039, 13.999, 14.087, 14.05, 14.083, 14.136, 14.124, 14.189, 14.149, 14.182, 14.281, 14.177, 14.297, 14.268, 14.454, 14.295]

G_cal_values = [-8.553610547563503, -8.085853602272588, -7.98491731861732, -7.852060056526794, -7.550944423333883, -7.569289687795749, -7.547088847268468, -7.544445036682168, -7.480698829329534, -7.184407435874912, -7.382606680295108, -7.2231275160942054, -7.093385973539046, -7.0473097125206685, -6.775012624594927, -6.814667514017907, -6.719898703328146, -6.741699011193633, -6.483121454948265, -6.320533066162438, -6.216044707275117, -6.037365656714626, -6.058593802250578, -6.0203190345840865, -6.036176430437363, -5.817887798572345, -5.838439347527171, -5.864922270102037, -5.755152671040021, -5.7709095683554725, -5.729226240967218, -5.606533007538604, -5.5817719334376905, -5.578993138005095, -5.62616747769538, -5.648413591916503, -5.611676700504294, -5.557722166623976, -5.5584623064502825, -5.425878164810264, -5.582204334985258, -5.529395790688368, -5.560750195967957, -5.433224654816512, -5.4751198268734385, -5.4592032005417215, -5.514591770369543, -5.580278698184566, -5.520695348050357, -5.501615700174841, -5.578645415877418, -5.692203332547151, -5.569497861450115, -5.335209902666812, -5.470963349023013, -5.44265375533589, -5.538541653702721, -5.355732832969871, -5.318164588926453, -5.376154615199398, -5.372133774215322, -5.361689907587619, -5.37608154921679, -5.412657572197508, -5.454613589602333, -5.339384591430104, -5.367511403407703, -5.258069473329993, -5.347580031901464, -4.9905279263992, -5.445096880253789, -5.192885553786512, -5.2983352094538505, -5.3930571447307365, -5.057910469318639, -5.32585105504838, -5.238649399637653, -5.122431894813153, -5.084559296025157, -5.139042420486851, -4.9919273140342915, -5.103619454431522, -5.017946144298159, -4.98136832081144, -5.084355565584671, -5.048634391386494, -4.887073481359435, -5.074683293771264, -5.050703776716202, -5.104772289705188, -4.9597601680524415, -4.971489935988787, -4.895283369236485, -4.9859511256778974, -4.840717539517584, -4.815665714699117, -4.937635861879118, -4.887219819695687, -4.813729758415283, -4.82667464608015, -4.865176481168528, -4.885105289124561, -4.887072278243732]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


plt.scatter(G_mag_values,G_cal_values)

ax.minorticks_on()
ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5')
ax.grid(which='minor', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5')
fig.set_size_inches(10,7)
best_fit_Y_G = []
slope_G, intercept_G, r_value_G, p_value_G, std_err_G = stats.linregress(G_mag_values,G_cal_values)
for value_G in G_mag_values:
    best_fit_Y_G.append(intercept_G + slope_G*value_G)
plt.plot(G_mag_values, best_fit_Y_G, 'r', label = 'Best fit')
plt.title('M67 Calibration graph for G filter')
plt.xlabel('Real magnitude')
plt.ylabel('Measured magnitude')
plt.show()


curve_G = np.polyfit(G_mag_values,G_cal_values,1)
print('G filter polyfit line: slope {}; intercept = {}'.format(curve_G[0],curve_G[1]))
print('G filter linregress: slope {}; intercept = {}'.format(slope_G,intercept_G))
```

When I run this, it prints the values for slope and intercept from the best_fit_Y_G and curve_G, but it doesnt display the plot at all. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copy/pasted and run your code.

```
curve_G = np.polyfit(G_mag_values,G_cal_values,1)
```

That line gives me error. Then I imported numpy as np and problem solved.

[output figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP67K.png)